# Emulation program broke because game updated from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: windows

I have no idea who the developers of the emulator are; so I have no way to reach out to them for a fix.

I'm hoping to find someone here who would be willing to take a look at the emulator to see what would need to be done to get it working for the 64 bit version of the game.  If there is a better place to post or a different forum, please let me know.

I have zero experience with reverse engineering, but I love the game; so I'm hoping to find someone willing to help.  If you are interested, let me know; and I'll share a copy of the emulator.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. What is the emulator's name and can you provide it? 2. Same as 1, but about the game. You litterally ask question without providing a single detail about the question itself

Comment: Here is a link to the executable.  The emulator creates multiple instances of the game; so that I can run multiple accounts simultaneously.  If you need more than that, let me know. https://mega.nz/folder/WAQUXayC#UmOXLkFcSUAy_mVtCqp-PA

Comment: The game is Star Wars: The Old Republic.  The game updated from 32 bit to 64 bit at the beginning of the year.  Something with how the game generates instances has broken.

Comment: You mean the emulator is [this thing](https://isboxer.com/)?

Comment: I don't know what that is.  The emulator was posted on a World of Warcraft fan forum.  Were you able to determine if it would be a big project to update the emulator to 64 bit?